# Does variable shadowing work on all compilers in C++?

Tags: c++

I ran this code on Leetcode.com but it prints random numbers. It works on my local machine, however. Anybody know if variable shadowing is supposed to work across all compilers?

```
    int carry = 0;
    if (1) {
        int carry = carry + 1;
        cout << carry << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Yes scoping rules are part of the language.

Comment: ***I ran this code on Leetcode.com but it prints random numbers. It works on my local machine, however. Anybody know if variable shadowing is supposed to work across all compilers?*** Since `carry` is uninitialized the result is undefined behavior which means anything can happen.

Comment: Your compiler can help you with this: if you compile your example with the appropriate flags, you'll find `int carry = 0;` is unused (`-Wunused-variable`), and `int carry = carry + 1;` is unintialized (`-Wuninitialized`).  Those two pieces of information might have helped you identify the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shadowing is defined by the C++ standard, and must work on all conforming compilers.

Your code prints garbage, because `carry` in `carry + 1` reads the new variable (which isn't initialized at that point yet, causing UB), not the old one.

Comment: Oh that would make sense then. Why isn't it reading the older "carry" if the inner carry is undefined yet?

Comment: @StarckOverflar The point where variable name becomes visible is different from when its initialization is complete. Hard to say why it was made this way. You could do something useful with the variable in its own initializer, like take its address (which is legal even then) and pass it somewhere.

Comment: @StarckOverflar • *Why isn't it reading the older "carry" if the inner carry is undefined yet?*  The inner carry **is** defined, it just **is not** initialized.

Answer (score 3):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned:

> The shadowing is defined by the C++ standard, and must work on all
> conforming compilers.

So because `carry` inside `carry+1` takes the **new** `carry`, and that `carry` isn't initialized, anything can happened, as it's Undefined Behavior (UB).

Mind you, UB doesn't mean that the output is random, it just mean that anything can be printed out (so it may be consistent), and in some case you **will** get the correct answer.

Edit:

To the question "Why isn't it reading the older "carry" if the inner carry is undefined yet?".

It is designed this way within compiler, as @Nikita Demodov mentioned:

> (For some reason) A variable is declared once it's identifier is reached. That's why
> the `carry` after the `=` is the newly declared `carry`, rather that the
> `carry` outside the `if`.

And as said [in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160#:%7E:text=Global%20scope%20A%20global%20name,with%20an%20implicit%20global%20namespace.&text=Local%20scope%20A%20name%20declared,referred%20to%20as%20%22locals%22.):

> You can hide names with global scope by explicitly declaring the same
> name in block scope. However, global-scope names can be accessed using
> the scope-resolution operator (`::`).

In other word, whenever there is a local variable defined with same name as that of a global variable, the compiler will give precedence to the local variable.

Comment: Note: For a very smart and thought out reason (that I don't know, but if *you* do, please tell me), a variable is declared once it's identifier is reached. That's why the the `carry` after the `=` is the newly declared `carry`, rather that the `carry` outside the `if`.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Thanks for the clarifier, I'll edit the answer. Btw, I don't know the reason either...

Comment: @NikitaDemodov Sometimes you may need to have linked node structures where a node may point to itself. In such case, referring to variable within its initialisation can be useful: `Node node { .next = &node };`

Comment: @eerorika Ah, thank you! Now I feel stupid for not thinking of that myself... :) Although it is quite impressive that the creators of C have already thought of most such things back then. Really makes you appreciate the amount of work that goes into designing a language!